NVMe enclosure compatability: drive won't fit
I have an NVMe drive and an M.2 enclosure. However my drive doesn't easily slot into the enclosure connector like I expected, so I'm wondering if I've bought the wrong enclosure type, or the enclosure is faulty somehow.
Here is a picture of both side by side:

Are these two compatible?
thanks in advance!

M.2 SATA is not the same as and is not compatible with M.2 NVMe.

not necessarily. Your SATA adapter says it accepts B & M key, but if you have an NVME that only has M-key it will not fit in the same slot: https://www.delock.de/infothek/M.2/images/keys-b-m_engl.jpg (from https://www.delock.de/infothek/M.2/M.2_e.html).

The slot keys only allow more generic daughter cards. Yours (B-keyed) will accept B or B+M keyed daughter cards while an M-keyed slot will accept either M or B+M keyed. Neither will accept cards that are only keyed for the opposite type. a B slot will not accept an M key, and an M will not accept a B key alone.

"It appears they're supposed to be physically compatible though, and these two don't appear to be" - No; The two devices in your screenshot were never going to work.  You have a M.2 SSD adapter, which has no compatibility for M.2 NVMe drives, thus making the pairing incompatible.  Even if the NVMe device fit, the adapter would have never actually detected the drive, since it only has hardware to support SATA drives.

@IanNewson - Clearly I made a typo.  Your M.2 SATA adapter that is clearly designed for only NGFF cards based on its size and shape. The identifying information wasn’t enough to determine a manufacturer which means a specification page couldn’t be found

Not all M.2 drives are NVMe – cheaper ones are SATA – and the two use different connections – some of the pins on your M.2 connector are for PCI-Express (i.e. NVMe) and some are used for SATA.
M.2 slots on PC mainboards have both connections routed to somewhere since they have both PCI-Express and a SATA controller anyway, but most enclosures only have one or the other.
(Making a SATA-only M.2 enclosure is as cheap as making a generic SATA enclosure, but NVMe (PCI-Express) requires a more complex controller chip; and if the manufacturer tried to do both, then they'd probably have to throw in a USB-hub chip as well, making it a bit more expensive.)
In short, you need to get an M.2 NVMe enclosure.

It appears they're supposed to be physically compatible though, and these two don't appear to be

Many NVMe SSDs do not have the 'B key' notch (are M-key only) so that they could use two additional PCI-Express lanes – which are on pins 12-19, exactly the position that the B-key would cut out.
(But being "physically compatible" would be useless, since the SATA host controller in your enclosure couldn't talk to an NVMe (PCI-Express) device anyway.)

@IanNewson If it as sold as supporting "SATA only" (NGFF was also used but not so much this days) then you have no basis for requesting a refund, legal or moral, at all.

Well, let's say that regardless of the cutouts, they would still remain physically incompatible because the SSD uses data pins that are physically not wired up on the enclosure, and vice versa.

@IanNewson Unless you test it with a compatible drive you'll never know if it's faulty or not. But, if allowed by the terms of sale, you may return it alleging you selected a wrong product. Other than that no, it doesn't make sense because it was your mistake, undoubtedly, as thoroughly explained by this answer (and previous comment). Many people learned the exact same lesson many years ago.

And, for future reference, there are different sizes. Yours is a "2280". When buying an enclosure make sure 1. it's for NVMe and 2. it supports drives "2280" (or smaller).

"if they're supposed to be compatible physically but are not I will request a refund because it's faulty." - I don't have the product page, for the adapter you purchased, but the adapter itself does not claim it supports NVMe drives.  It specifically indicates only SATA support. I would also point out the NVMe SSD is longer than the adapter
